# Score (node) is registering multiple times and flashing when set to a visible colour?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collision-detection, game-physics

I have placed my scoreNode in line with the animated objects my character has to avoid and the scoreNode is flashing (when I set it to a visible blue colour) and often too many contacts are counted between the character and the scoreNode. So basically I think it is only generating the scores at each animation frame rather than just being a constant node. How do I change this to where it picks up the score normally?

p.s. I am new to swift and I try to make these questions as clear as I can so bear with me XD

Here's some code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let firstBody = contact.bodyA
        let secondBody = contact.bodyB

        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.Score && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.character || firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.character && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.Score{

            score += 1
            print(score)
        }
    }
```

this is inside my func all balls() :

```
let scoreNode = SKSpriteNode()

        scoreNode.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 7000)
        scoreNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height)
        scoreNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: scoreNode.size)
        scoreNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        scoreNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        scoreNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.Score
        scoreNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        scoreNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.character
        scoreNode.color = SKColor.blueColor()

//and

let ballarray: NSMutableArray = [blkball, brnball, yelball, bluball]
        let randomBall = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ballarray.count)))

        let randomItem = ballarray[randomBall]

        randomItem.addChild(scoreNode)

        randomItem.runAction(moveandremove)
```

Please help :)

Comment: answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007840/why-is-my-node-flashing-making-a-score-in-swift